# VSTO Sending the ActiveInlineResponse MailItem Fails

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

## Add In

I've created a VSTO Add-In for Outlook 2010 and up.  I have placed a "Send Confidential" button in the ribbon.  This button will set the `MailItem.Sensitivity = OlSensitivity.olConfidential` and then send the MailItem with `MailItem.Send()`.

## Problem

Everything works fine when dealing with a new email or a reply that is "Popped Out" (or in its own Inspector).  The problem arises when I have an Inline Response.  The button is there, I have it embedded in the TabSet TabComposeTools and the Tab TabMessage, so it is visible.  When the user clicks it, the `MailItem.Send();` call throws an exception "This method can't be used with an inline response mail item."

Is there any way to send the Active Inline Response?